# Why does RDP hit .bash_profile three times?

Tags: linux, rdp

Is RDP actually invoking three separate sessions when I log in?

I connect to a CentOS 7 laptop via RDP from my Win10 desktop. I've noticed that when I do this the personal paths that I have in `.bash_profile` are added to `$PATH` three times. This makes it appear that the RDP connection is executing my `.bash_profile` three separate times for one RDP login.

When I looked at `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log-<dtg>.gz` I have:

```
[20200325-12:05:19] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 37810
[20200325-12:05:19] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username <...> - socket: 12
[20200325-12:05:19] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
...
[20200325-12:05:19] [INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 4331
...
[20200325-12:05:19] [INFO ] Xvnc :10 -auth .Xauthority -geometry 3440x1440 -depth 32 -rfbauth <...>
<EOF>
```

I wrote a small script that writes the DTG to a .log file for each time the `.bash_profile` is run (sourced?), just to prove to myself that the file was indeed getting hit three times. The DTG from the .log file does not match the DTG of the above, all `.bash_profile` runs are one second later. This makes me think something else if going on.

```
Wed Mar 25 12:05:20 CDT 2020
Wed Mar 25 12:05:20 CDT 2020
Wed Mar 25 12:05:20 CDT 2020
```

Any tips as to what is going on and how to keep my `$PATH` from being added to so many times?